# query with regex in neo4j doesn't return the correct result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm tring to execute this query without succes

```
MATCH (t:Tweet)
WHERE  
    t.full_text =~ '(?i).*sciacalli.*'  AND
    t.created_at>'2018/01/01' AND t.created_at<'2020/04/25'
RETURN t
```

The output shuld be this one

```
"full_text": "RT @catlatorre: Sciacalli.\n
                  Comunque vada sempre sciacalli 
                  siete #KobeBryant https://t.co/*********",
"created_at": "2020/01/26 22:49:51",
```

I don't understand way the regex not match

But if modify the query as follow

```
MATCH (t:Tweet)
WHERE  
    t.full_text CONTAINS 'sciacalli'  AND
    t.created_at>'2018/01/01' AND t.created_at<'2020/04/25'
RETURN t
```

I get the correct result. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value contains line endings. Include the DOTALL option with ?s

```
MATCH (t:Tweet)
WHERE  
    t.full_text =~ '(?is).*sciacalli.*'  AND
    t.created_at>'2018/01/01' AND t.created_at<'2020/04/25'
RETURN t
```